# How to make this jQuery code work on version 3.2.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a function which can download free resource and apply or modify my work. I used this function to make my website by setting all divs to `display=none` and with clicking on a button, the corresponding div display `style` will become `block`.

Everything was working fine until I add a music player that the creator use higher jQuery library (3.2.1 > 1.5.2).

Everything works great like before, but when I click on button to play the music, I can't go back or go to other menus.

Debugger error is :

> uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById is not a function

But if I don't click on play button, everything is normal.

```
function openPage(pageName) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("page");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";  
}
```

Comment: from my little knowledge i think because this code not compatible format for modern jquery so it's has any way to improve it

Comment: Your question is hard to understand because you have used no punctuation. There's no reason why [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) [shouldn't work](https://jsfiddle.net/4ra5p8bx/).

Answer (score 1):

Jquery does not prevent vanilla Javascript from running normally.
And as your code is simply Javascript, and from what it appears there are no mistakes within it, it's hard to figure out why such an error would appear. This has nothing to do with Jquery.

The only foreseeable error would be:

**pageName** is not passed as an argument;

**pageName** is passed, but is not a string;

no element with the id equal to the **pageName**'s value exists within your document.

You could slightly improve your code by writing it in this way:

```
function openPage(pageName) {
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('page')).map(page => page.style.display = 'none');
    document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";  
};
```

You could make it 'more fullproof' by adding some checks:

```
function openPage(pageName) {
    if (pageName && (typeOf pageName === 'string')) {
        Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('page')).map(page => page.style.display = 'none');
        var target = document.getElementById(pageName);
        if (target) { target.style.display = "block" };
    }
};
```

And yu could improve it by also loggin to the console, when a check has failed, for debugging:

```
function openPage(pageName) {
    if (pageName && (typeOf pageName === 'string')) {
        Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('page')).map(page => page.style.display = 'none');
        var target = document.getElementById(pageName);
        if (target) { 
            target.style.display = "block" 
        } else {
            console.log('No element found, with the ID of:' , pageName)
        };
    } else {
        console.log('Error in openPage() : The provided [pagename] argument must be a [string]. Provided value for [pageName] is:', pageName);
    }
};
```

Comment: thank you for help me i'll try to improve from your code but doesn't work like my previous code but when i click on Play audio function every "openPage" is broken so i think now the problem is from my another .js file :(

so if u have time but it ok if not // i very appreciate that toyr answer above :)
https://github.com/greghub/green-audio-player